# Hom$_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z )=0 $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hom$_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z )=0 $. How to prove this? (Here Hom is denoting the Hom functor.)

Comment: You should require $n \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f\colon \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a homomorphism.

Then, for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, you have $nx=0$, so $f(nx)=nf(x)=0$. What are the integers $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $nz=0$?